# How to log communication to GAE endpoint

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I created some simple app for android tutorial https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

I wonder how can I get log for communication between application and web service. I want to see URL's, Headers, Bodies of requests and responses.
 I'm using the default (generated) client library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see your logs at **Google Cloud Platform**'s **Logging** menu: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer